# How does mapping work on Android (ROSjava)?

Tags: ros, rosjava, android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

I came across these sample applications for android : [android_apps](https://github.com/rosjava/android_apps)

There are three applications : make_a_map, map_manager, map_nav

I looked into the source code for make_a_map and could not comprehend if it is using mapping somewhere. I can see the following imports

[image: imports]

then I see the nodemain being initialized and executed
[image: map_view initialized]

then

[image: map_view executed]

Even if mapping is involved, it must be visual map, how is it being converted to occupancy grid (I saw one snapshot in the **issues** section on github repo!)?

My Question:

1. Does the app **make_a_map** do mapping on Android phone (standalone)?
2. In case mapping does happen on android phone what algorithm is used to map image to occupancy grid?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/304037/how-does-mapping-work-on-android-(rosjava)?/) by [vvyogi](https://answers.ros.org/users/29579/vvyogi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 53 on 2018-09-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`VisualizationView` is a component inside `android_core`, namely a ROSJava node that does what you say.

You can take a look at its code here: https://github.com/rosjava/android_core/blob/kinetic/android_15/src/org/ros/android/view/visualization/VisualizationView.java.

You can also take a look around all the visualization components in the same repository; it's all open source.

Hope it helps!

Edit / update: The `VisualizationView` is made up of different layers, which draw things one on top of the other if I'm not mistaken. In particular, the view should have an [OccupancyGridLayer](https://github.com/rosjava/android_core/blob/kinetic/android_15/src/org/ros/android/view/visualization/layer/OccupancyGridLayer.java). This type of layer subscribes to an `OccupancyGrid` topic type, and updates the values according to the information received (here's the callback hook when a new message arrives: https://github.com/rosjava/android_core/blob/kinetic/android_15/src/org/ros/android/view/visualization/layer/OccupancyGridLayer.java#L163-L173). From that point, you can see how the layer populates the view according to the values in the occupancy grid (I'm not super familiar with the details).

---

Originally posted by [jubeira](https://answers.ros.org/users/29146/jubeira/) with karma: 1054 on 2018-09-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [vvyogi](https://answers.ros.org/users/29579/vvyogi/) on 2018-09-24**:
Hi jubeira, Thanks for answering. I want to know if there is any active development going on with rosjava ? Of the three developers listed on github, you are the only one active. Please provide some information about the future of ROSjava.

**Comment by [jubeira](https://answers.ros.org/users/29146/jubeira/) on 2018-09-24**:
Hi @vvyogi. I'm currently doing maintenance of the codebase on best-effort basis when I have spare time, trying to review PRs from the community and submitting some more.

If your question is whether it still supported, the answer is yes.

**Comment by [vvyogi](https://answers.ros.org/users/29579/vvyogi/) on 2018-09-27**:
Thank you for the response. It cleared some of my doubts.

**Comment by [jubeira](https://answers.ros.org/users/29146/jubeira/) on 2018-09-27**:
yw! Please feel free to mark the answer as accepted so others can make use of it as well :)
Let me know if you need further clarifications about the original question, or open another one if needed.

**Comment by [vvyogi](https://answers.ros.org/users/29579/vvyogi/) on 2018-09-27**:
Hi Jubeira, If it is possible please do add more information to your answer regarding the mapping technique used. Meanwhile, I am trying to read the code you pointed at. It seems there is lot of interesting stuff in the roscore. If documentation were better it would benefit a larger audience. Thanks

**Comment by [jubeira](https://answers.ros.org/users/29146/jubeira/) on 2018-09-27**:
I just updated the question a bit.